# Cyclic Groups: Modulo operations in exponents possible?

Tags: computational-complexity, cryptography

I'm trying to follow [CCat's Zero Knowledge Proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/134505/37625) example, which was quite similar to the $\Sigma$-protocol example in my books. And whith both of them I'm struggeling.
When I try to test CCats Example:

Setup:

> Cyclic Group $G$ of size $p=17$. Generator $g=3$.

Alice:

> knows $x=7$
>   calculates $y=g^x=3^7\mod{17}=11$
>   generates $r=13$
>   sends $a=g^r=3^{13}\mod{17}=12$ to Bob

Bob:

> generates $c=15$ and sends it to Alice

Alice:

> sends $z=cx+r\mod{p}=(15\cdot 7+13)\mod{17}=16$ to Bob

Bob:

> checks if $g^z = y^c a$
>   $3^{16}\mod{17} = 11^{15} \cdot 12 \mod{17}$
>   $1=15$ *(not good)*

Without the Modulo, the comparison seams mathematical correct to me:

> $g^{cx+r}=g^{x^c}\cdot g^r$

And the results are correct, in that case.

For some reasons $g^{cx+r\mod{p}}$ (or any variations) operation don't work for my examples. I also couldn't find any Congruence rules for a modulo within a power operation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to MO! This question does not appear to be a question related to current mathematical research and as such does not seem appropriate for this site. I believe what you are missing is that the *multiplicative* group generated by 3 modulo 17 is not a group of order 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me expand on the comment of **@quid**.

You should consider the *ring* $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$ of integers modulo $17$, which happens to be a field, as $17$ is prime. This is a cyclic group of order $17$ when regarded additively, whereas $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^{\star} = \mathbb{Z}_{17} \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is a cyclic group of order $16$ with respect to multiplication, of which your $g$ happens to be a generator.

Now you have
$$
g^{u} = g^{v} \pmod{17}  \qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad u \equiv v \pmod{16}.
$$

So the correct calculation is $z = c x + r \equiv 16 \pmod{16}$. And then you have indeed
$$
15 \equiv g^{z} \equiv g^{c x + r} \equiv (g^{x})^{c} g^{r} \equiv y^{c} g^{r} \equiv 14 \cdot 12 \pmod{17}.
$$

Note also that your $\LaTeX$  code

```
   g^{cx+r}=g^{x^c}\cdot g^r
```

which yields the possibly ambiguous $$g^{cx+r}=g^{x^c}\cdot g^r,$$
is a misprint for the correct

```
  g^{c x + r} = (g^{x})^{c} \cdot g^{r}
```

which yields $$g^{c x + r} = (g^{x})^{c} \cdot g^{r}.$$